# How to see data in Store in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJs, I created a data Model in extJs then i create a store of that model and i am loading data on store using url, now **i want to see the data available in that store** , how i can do that?

My Data model code

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    proxy: {
        actionMethods: {create: "POST", read: "POST", update: "POST", destroy: "POST"},
        type: 'ajax'
    }
});
```

My Store code

```
var MyStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'MyModel',
    pageSize: 50,
    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    remoteGroup: true
});
```

How i am loading values in store

```
MyStore.load({url: 'xyz.json'});
```

Comment: How about logging MyStore to a console and inspecting it's children? There's a field (forgot it's name) which holds an array of all stored records.

Comment: Another easy way would be to just use the developer toolbar and check the request in the network tab. Take a look at the response and you can see the JSON returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger an explicit event after you initialize your store.

```
// This will ensure that the store is loaded before you log the records.
MyStore.on('load', function(store) {
    var records = store.getRange();

    console.log(records); // The data you want to see.
});
```

You can also add load event in the class. You may refer [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-listeners). The most important part is the `getRange()` method. This will return all the data from the store.

Answer (score 1):

You can add callback method when calling store load. For example:

```
MyStore.load({
    url: 'xyz.json',
    callback: function(records, operation, success){
        console.log(records);
    }
});
```

Read more here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load